# Poor UITableView performance when in UIPopoverController with custom background

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a following situation (testing on iPad, iOS 5.1):

1. There is a UIPopoverController with UINavigationController inside and custom popover background view (subclass of UIPopoverBackgroundView).
2. There is a generic UIViewController (let's call it VC1) as the root VC in the Navigation Controller.
3. I push another UIViewController (VC2) with UITableView on the Navigation Controller stack.

Effect:
Table scrolling is choppy (looks like 10-15 fps). For testing purposes I use a simplest possible UITableView, without images etc. so it's NOT caused by bad UITableView implementation.

- Scrolling is not choppy if the VC2 is the root view controller of
  Navigation Controller, even with the custom Popover background.
- It's also not choppy if pushed as the second VC but I don't use custom bg view class for UIPopoverController.

I log each of the overriden methods inside my UIPopoverBackgroundView subclass, and they aren't called constantly or anything, which could theoretically cause performance hit. I'm going to debug the problem further but maybe someone has already solved it before?

Or maybe someone has good suggestions on how to find the culprit? I tried looking into time profiler for offending function calls, but I didn't find much there...

Comment: Are you caching the UITableViewCells?

Comment: Yes of course. As I said UITableView delegate and dataSource implementation seems to be fine. The table works like a charm in every other situation. Two conditions must exist at the same time to cause the choppy scrolling: table view added as a second VC in NavCtrl and a custom Popover background used.

Comment: You might want to try the Core Animation instrument to see how much / if there is excessive blending going on when you've got the bad configuration in place.